# (Re)Using HEPA filters at a Convention

Tags: covid-19, infection-control, air-filter-purifier

We were planning to bring residential HEPA filters to a convention to reduce potential viral load. However, the filters are rated for 3-6 months, and it seems wasteful to discard the filters after a three day convention. Are there risks to leaving the filter in before taking the machine to the convention and/or keeping the filters in the machine when returning the machine to residential use. Is there best practice for this use case?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is medical science on-topic, but we would need much more information on exactly how they would be deployed (room size, airflow rates, attendance numbers, number of filter units, filtration rate etc.) , and (not least) some evidence that you've made some effort to look at the literature on this topic before we could even begin to answer something like this.

Comment: This is a question for the manufacturer of the filters.